# When I create a new project I can only choose "Other Projects", "Non-Qt Project" and "Import Project"

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

I have a problem with ubuntu-sdk

I installed it following the guide here [Get-Started](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/#step-get-toolkit)

But then when I start ubuntu-sdk and try tro create a new project I can only choose "Other Projects", "Non-Qt Project" and "Import Project", 
but "Projects > Ubuntu " simply **does not exist**.

To Install Ubuntu SDK I ran the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa
sudo apt-get install qtcreator
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk
```

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 32-bit

Anyone can help? 
Thank You.

Here's a screen:

[image: Ubuntu SDK]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual solution instead of installing 12.04 is as fallow:

Go to Tools/Options/Build & Run -> Qt Versions 
Click on "Add..." and navigate to this path /usr/bin/qmake
So it should look like this:
[image: Qt Versions]

Then set it as the default version for the "Desktop" kit (Build & Run -> Kits).
So it should looks like this:
[image: Kits]

After that just **restart** Qt Creator and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

In the *Write your first app* step (actually the next one), is included a link to the *[phone app tutorial](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/tutorials/getting-started/currency-converter-phone-app/)* which follows this steps:

1. In Qt Creator, press Ctrl + N to create a new project *(here is where you are)*
2. Select the Projects > Ubuntu > Simple Touch UI template and click Choose… (I'm guessing that "Ubuntu" is **scrolling down the list**)
3. Give the project CurrencyConverter as a Name. You can leave the Create in: field as the default and then click Next.
4. You can optionally set up a revision control system such as Bazaar in the final step, but that’s outside the scope of this tutorial. Click on Finish.
5. Replace the Column component and all of its children, and replace them with the Page as shown below, and then save it with Ctrl+S: (here is a bunch of code, which is not important for solving the problem)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the problem is that "Projects > Ubuntu " simply does not exist..
I can only choose "Other Projects", "Non-Qt Project" and "Import Project"..

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I just solved it this way:

I removed Ubuntu 13.04 and Installed Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS,
Then I ran:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qtcreator
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk
```

Now everything seems to be fine.

[image]

Thanks to everyone for the help!