# Qt Creator and UbuntuSDK

Tags: development, qt, sdk

I am installing Ubuntu SDK with Qt Creator by following this [link](http://developer.ubuntu.com/apps/create/get-the-sdk/)
but when I launch Qt Creator there is no option for Ubuntu's projects (Projects > Ubuntu > Simple Touch UI),only default console projects.

How can I add these solutions in Qt Creator?

P.S.: Sorry, for my English

Comment: I try to install SDK for UbuntuPhone

Answer (score 0):

That same problem has been bugging me for a while. But yay, **there is a solution**!

It seems, that for some odd reason, the creator is installed in an unusable state. It is not set to the right **Qt version**. To remedy the problem you have to follow the steps supplied in the answer this question:
[Remedy for missing templates](https://askubuntu.com/a/354525/210644)