# Can't create a project

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-sdk, qt-creator

I installed the IDE, following the instructions on your website. Than I went on to:
http://developer.ubuntu.com/apps/qml/tutorial/

The tutorial says:

1. In Qt Creator, press **Ctrl**+**N** to create a new project.
2. Select the **Projects -> Ubuntu -> Simple Touch UI** template and click **Choose…**

...but a thing like that does not exist. The dialogue I get looks like this:

[image: This is what the dialogue look like]

I have tried to install the IDE, with or without the PPA, but I always get the same result.
And as it seems, I am not the only one with that problem: [The other one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/368240/qt-creator-and-ubuntusdk/374604#374604)

Is there a working way to install the SDK? Or at least a workaround? Something like installing the the templates separate?

Comment: Make sure you are on 13.10 and that you have installed the package `ubuntu-sdk` directly, not the ppa. The webpage is a little behind.

Comment: huh? I do not understand that. I am using 13.10. But what do you mean by installing directly?

Comment: what version of ubuntu are you using? how did you install qt-creator?

Comment: using ubuntu 13.10

Comment: followed the instructions on the website, as explained in the post.

Comment: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk

Comment: yes, that was my point. if you are on 13.10, do not use the ppa. just install `ubuntu-sdk` directly. the web page instructions are outdated.

Comment: By install directly you mean: use the "ubuntu software center"?

Comment: Ok, we're getting into chat, which we need to avoid, but I don't have a definitive statement to put into an answer. Most likely, you need to remove the ppa. then run `sudo apt-get update`, then `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk`.

Comment: Nope, no effect. It does not matter how I install. That would have been odd anyway.

Comment: So still the same problem. Can't do a thing. Hard to produce something beautiful, if you get smacked hard trying to take just the first step.

Comment: qt-creator shows the correct options, very different from your screen shot, on my system. I doubt you have removed the ppa fully and restored/reinstalled the package list. With respect, I can't respond to more comments. You may want to edit your question to be about how to fix after installing the ppa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yay, found the solution.

For some odd reason the Ubuntu SDK is installed in an unusable state. The IDE does not know the **Qt version** to use. To remedy the problem you have to follow the steps described in following answer:
[Steps to set the right Qt version](https://askubuntu.com/a/354525/210644)

Thanks for that well explained answer, to [Majster-pl](https://askubuntu.com/users/73045/majster-pl)