# QtCreator doesn't let me create Ubuntu Touch apps!

Tags: application-development, xubuntu, ubuntu-touch, qt-creator

I've gone through the instructions for installing the SDK found here: http://developer.ubuntu.com/apps/create/get-the-sdk/ using Xubuntu 12.04. Everything went well except, for some reason, QtCreator won't let me create a QML Ubuntu Touch app!

While the IDE looks like it's ready to create Ubuntu Touch apps, when I click on 'Create New Project' I don't have an option in any of the project types to create a Touch app.

Can anyone advise me as to what might be going wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. This question and the accepted answer fixed it for me:
[https://askubuntu.com/questions/338387/when-i-create-a-new-project-i-can-only-choose-other-projects-non-qt-project/354525#*=*](https://askubuntu.com/questions/338387/when-i-create-a-new-project-i-can-only-choose-other-projects-non-qt-project/354525#_=_)

To sum it up:
1. Open Qt Creator
2. Go To Tools > Options >Build & Run > Qt Versions
3. Press Add
4. Navigate to and select /usr/bin/qmake
5. Go to the "Kits" Tab and select *Desktop (default)*
6. Under "Qt Version" select Qt 5.0.2 (System)
7. Restart Qt creator and create a new project, the options you want should be there.